# How to restrict selection of radio button to one time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to restrict the multiple counting in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgvto6k1/3/) . So once I rated by selecting a radio button I want to store this information so that the counter won't add more "rates". How can I restrict eace counter to go up only once?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="stars float-left">
    <div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5" />
        <label for="star5"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4">
        <label for="star4"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3" />
        <label for="star3"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2">
        <label for="star2"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1" />
        <label for="star1"></label>
    </p>
    <span class="rate">Rate! (62)</span>
</div>

<div class="stars float-left">
    <div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5" />
        <label for="star5"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4">
        <label for="star4"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3" />
        <label for="star3"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2">
        <label for="star2"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1" />
        <label for="star1"></label>
    </p>
    <span class="rate">Rate! (20)</span>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$('.stars input:radio').click(function() {
    str_rate = $(this).closest('div').find('span.rate');
    var rate_string = $(str_rate).text();
    var rate = parseInt(rate_string.substring(rate_string.indexOf("(") + 1,rate_string.indexOf(")")),10) + 1;
    $(str_rate).text("Rate! (" + rate + ")");
});
```

Comment: You mean that **only** the first click on the radio will increment the counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgvto6k1/10/

You could disable the radios for this, by adding `$("input", $(this).parents("div")).attr("disabled", true);` line at the end of your click handler.

But, this way is not secure! Any one could re-enable the radio buttons (or re-attach the events) you should add some server side checks as well.

```js
$('.stars input:radio').click(function() {
  str_rate = $(this).closest('div').find('span.rate');
  var rate_string = $(str_rate).text();
  var rate = parseInt(rate_string.substring(rate_string.indexOf("(") + 1, rate_string.indexOf(")")), 10) + 1;
  $(str_rate).text("Rate! (" + rate + ")");

  $("input", $(this).parents("div")).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars float-left">
  <div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5" />
    <label for="star5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4">
    <label for="star4"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3" />
    <label for="star3"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2">
    <label for="star2"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1" />
    <label for="star1"></label>
  </p>
  <span class="rate">Rate! (62)</span>
</div>

<div class="stars float-left">
  <div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5" />
    <label for="star5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4">
    <label for="star4"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3" />
    <label for="star3"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2">
    <label for="star2"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1" />
    <label for="star1"></label>
  </p>
  <span class="rate">Rate! (20)</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your event fires **ONLY** if the radio button was checked. I have modified your code as follows: (http://jsfiddle.net/mgvto6k1/7/)

```js
$('input:radio[name="rating"]').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           str_rate = $(this).closest('div').find('span.rate');
    var rate_string = $(str_rate).text();
    var rate = parseInt(rate_string.substring(rate_string.indexOf("(") + 1,rate_string.indexOf(")")),10) + 1;
    $(str_rate).text("Rate! (" + rate + ")");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars float-left">
    <div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
       <p><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5" /><label for="star5"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4"><label for="star4"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3" /><label for="star3"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2"><label for="star2"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1" /><label for="star1"></label>
    </p>
    <span class="rate">Rate! (62)</span>
</div>
           
              <div class="stars float-left">
    <div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
       <p><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5" /><label for="star5"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4"><label for="star4"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3" /><label for="star3"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2"><label for="star2"></label><input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1" /><label for="star1"></label>
    </p>
    <span class="rate">Rate! (20)</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgvto6k1/15/)** if that what you looking for, you have just to disable the radio buttons after the rate, so like this the user can just rate one time, add the following code :

```
$(this).siblings().attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

**Full JS :**

```
$('.stars input:radio').click(function() {
    str_rate = $(this).closest('div').find('span.rate');
    var rate_string = $(str_rate).text();
    var rate = parseInt(rate_string.substring(rate_string.indexOf("(") + 1,rate_string.indexOf(")")),10) + 1;
    $(str_rate).text("Rate! (" + rate + ")");

    $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I think I understand your question, you want to only increment the counter once per row of checkboxes? You will want to unbind the click handler once a checkbox has been selected. I have made the change in the provided snippet

```js
$('.stars input:radio').click(function () {
    str_rate = $(this).closest('div').find('span.rate');
    var rate_string = $(str_rate).text();
    var rate = parseInt(rate_string.substring(rate_string.indexOf("(") + 1, rate_string.indexOf(")")), 10) + 1;
    $(str_rate).text("Rate! (" + rate + ")");
    $(this).siblings('input').unbind('click');
});
```

```html
<div class="stars float-left">
    <div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5" />
        <label for="star5"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4">
        <label for="star4"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3" />
        <label for="star3"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2">
        <label for="star2"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1" />
        <label for="star1"></label>
    </p> <span class="rate">Rate! (62)</span>

</div>
<div class="stars float-left">
    <div class="rating" style="width:99%"></div>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5" />
        <label for="star5"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4">
        <label for="star4"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3" />
        <label for="star3"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2">
        <label for="star2"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1" />
        <label for="star1"></label>
    </p> <span class="rate">Rate! (20)</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the radio button group once the user has made their decision.

So your code would now look like:

```
$('.stars input:radio').click(function() {
    str_rate = $(this).closest('div').find('span.rate');
    var rate_string = $(str_rate).text();
    var rate = parseInt(rate_string.substring(rate_string.indexOf("(") + 1,rate_string.indexOf(")")),10) + 1;
    $(str_rate).text("Rate! (" + rate + ")");
    $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", "true");
});
```